# Linq "join" or "GroupJoin" not compiling?? "Cannot resolve symbol 'GroupJoin'"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Maybe my eyes are crossed as I've been coding all day, but I decided to use a linq expression and it doesn't compile on keywords... Note this works in linqPad.

```
    using System.Linq;
            public IQueryable<CompanyPerson> PersonsFlattened()
            {

                var contacts = from person in Person
                           join companyPerson in CompanyPerson on person.Id equals companyPerson.PersonId into companyPersonGroups
                           from companyPerson in companyPersonGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new
                           {
                               ContactPerson = person,
                               ContactCompany = companyPerson.Company
                           };
}
```

For some reason "join" on line 2 gives me an error

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'GroupJoin'"

.

I've even tried the other way.

```
var contacts2 = Person.GroupJoin(CompanyPerson,
                person => person.Id,
                companyPerson => companyPerson.PersonId,
                (person, companyPersonGroups) =>
                    new
                    {
                        person = person,
                        companyPersonGroups = companyPersonGroups
                    }
                ).SelectMany(
                    temp0 => temp0.companyPersonGroups.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (temp0, companyPerson) =>
                        new
                        {
                            ContactPerson = temp0.person,
                            ContactCompany = companyPerson.Company
                        }
                );
```

and I get the same thing, any thoughts? Am I missing some reference you have to have for expressions? I traversed through the object explorer but didn't see anything I didn't already have included.  It's a web api 2 project .net 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the GroupJoin compile issue, for some reason it doesn't compile correctly with the var contact = xxx

I had to return a QueryAll(Person)

```
 return _contextProvider.QueryAll<Person>().GroupJoin(...)...
```

This was final solution. Does a left sql join and gets persons even if they don't have a company associated to them.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Person> PersonsFlattened()
    {
        //return _contextProvider.QueryAll<Person>();

        var contacts = from person in _contextProvider.QueryAll<Person>()
                       join companyPerson in CompanyPersons() on person.Id equals companyPerson.PersonId into companyPersonGroups
                       from companyPerson in companyPersonGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new Person()
                       {
                           FirstName = person.FirstName,
                           LastName = person.LastName

                       };

        return contacts;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're providing a type `CompanyPerson` rather than a value as the first argument:

```
var contacts2 = Person.GroupJoin(companyPerson,
                person => person.Id,
                companyPerson => companyPerson.PersonId,
                (person, companyPersonGroups) =>
                    new
                    {
                        person = person,
                        companyPersonGroups = companyPersonGroups
                    }
                ).SelectMany(
                    temp0 => temp0.companyPersonGroups.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (temp0, companyPerson) =>
                        new
                        {
                            ContactPerson = temp0.person,
                            ContactCompany = companyPerson.Company
                        }
                );
```

Comment: I still get the same problem on GroupJoin, I should mention the query works fine in linqpad. "Cannot resolve 'GroupJoin'"

Comment: Pheonixblade9, you were also correct on your part about my CompanyPerson but that wasn't the reason it didn't recognize the GroupJoin